# add watermark and scale the video in Batch using ffmpeg

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm doing batch video editing using FFMPEG and I want to combined those two command in one:

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i s.png -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10" "Logo\%%~na.mp4"
```

and

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vf scale=1920:-2,setsar=1:1 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy "Logo\%%~na.mp4"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined command:

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i s.png -filter_complex "[0]scale=1920:-2,setsar=1[bg];[bg][1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy "Logo\%%~na.mp4"
```

Comment: Llogan: Can I add this too?
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -af "aeval='-val(0)':c=same" "AudioFix\%%~na.mp4"